# how to dump dom and render tree with webkit on command line

Tags: webkit

I had built webkit with qt.

Now I want to write a program

> input : an url or a html file.
>
> output: the input page's dom tree and render tree, without the effect
>   of js.

I knew that the built-in program "dumprendertree" suits for me, but I want to get the output on command line because I worked on an OS without X-windows. I don't know how to switch the dumprendertree'output to stdout.

Thank you very much for any suggestions.

Comment: DumpRenderTree need gtk or qt that it can know how to render object. So you need install either one?